# Images in an HTML email are not being sized?

Tags: html, css, image, email

If I save the email as HTML it displays the sized image, but when I view it as a `.msg` file the image is not being sized.  Here is my markup:

```
<p>
  <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>
   <img border=0 id="_x0000_i1026"
        src="http://www.mynevadacounty.com/NC/CEO/Resources/FridayMemo/FM-20121004-gold-dollar-sign.jpg"
        style='height:111px;width:150px'>
   <o:p></o:p>
  </span>
</p>
```

I noticed that the `img` tag is unclosed, could this cause the issue?  If not, can anyone suggest how to get the image to size correctly?

Comment: Closing the image tag might help, but I would definitely try using the `height` and `width` attributes rather than the inline style.

Comment: Image doesn't have a closing tag, it is a self close element like this <img />

Comment: @Alien Is that addressed to me? I know that. Adding the trailing slash is still closing the tag.

Comment: A little curious, but why wouldn't you just serve the proper sized image in the first place??

Comment: The email is generated from a CMS based system where users can add images from their desktop and then size as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height="111"` and `width="150"` to your image tag.

```
<img border=0 id="_x0000_i1026" height="111" width="150" src="..." style='height:111px;width:150px'>
```

Here is a good reference of what can be used:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/